# Divide two metrics in Google Cloud Monitoring / MQL

Tags: stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver, google-cloud-monitoring, monitoring-query-language

How do I compute the difference and ratio between two Stackdriver metrics in MQL?

There are two parts two this question, but I am grateful if you can help me with one:

1. Compute the difference between the two time series
2. Compute the ratio between the two time series. Addon if possible: The case that the denominator is null should be handled gracefully.

I got so far, but it does not yield the expected result (the resulting time series is always zero):

```
fetch global
| { t_0:
      metric 'custom.googleapis.com/http/server/requests/count'
      | filter
        (metric.service == 'service-a' && metric.uri =~ '/api/started')
      | align next_older(1m);
    t_1:
      metric 'custom.googleapis.com/http/server/requests/count'
      | filter
        (metric.service == 'service-a' && metric.uri =~ '/api/completed')
      | align next_older(1m)
  }
| outer_join 0
| div
```

Obviously, the code has been anonymized. What I want to accomplish is to track whether there is a difference between processes that have been started vs completed.

**EDIT / ADDITIONAL INFO 2021-11-18**

I used the [projects.timeSeries v3 API](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/ref_v3/rest/v3/projects.timeSeries/query) for further debugging. Apparently the outer_join operation assumes that the labels between the two timeseries are the same, which is not the case in my example.

**Does anybody know, how to delete the labels, so I can perform the join and aggregation?**

**EDIT / ADDITIONAL INFO 2021-11-19**

The aggregation now works as I managed to delete the labels using the `map drop[...]` maplet.

The challenge was indeed the labels as these labels are generated by the Spring Boot implementation of Micrometer. Since the labels are distinct between these two metrics the join operation was always empty for `join`, or only the second timeseries for `outer_join`.

Comment: Try the given solution and let me know the results after using align mean(1m)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I got so far. Now the aggregation works as the labels are deleted. I will update this example when I know more.

```
fetch global
| { 
    t_0:
      metric 'custom.googleapis.com/http/server/requests/count'
      | filter
        (metric.service == 'service-a' && metric.uri =~ '/api/started')
      | every (1m)
      | map drop [resource.project_id, metric.status, metric.uri, metric.exception, metric.method, metric.service, metric.outcome]
    ; t_1:
      metric 'custom.googleapis.com/http/server/requests/count'
      | filter
        (metric.service == 'service-a' && metric.uri =~ '/api/completed')
      | every (1m)
      | map drop [resource.project_id, metric.status, metric.uri, metric.exception, metric.method, metric.service, metric.outcome]
  }
| within   d'2021/11/18-00:00:00', d'2021/11/18-15:15:00'
| outer_join 0
| value val(0)-val(1)
```

Answer (score 2):

As I can see you want to know the ratio between the **server_req _count** when the process started and when it’s completed and you are using the **align next_older(1m)** which may fetch the most recent value in the period. So it would be possible when the process started the count would be zero. So I would recommend you to change the [aligner](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/v3/aggregation#aligners) to  **mean or max** to get the req_count during the process started and completed in a different time series.

```
align mean(1m)
```

Please see the documentation for more ways to do a ratio query:[Examples of Ratio Query](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/mql/examples?hl=en#qlx-ratio-ratio)

Answer (score 0):

After using the [map add / map drop](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/mql/reference#value-tabop) operators like in your own answer, make sure to use `outer_join 0,0` which will give you a full outer join. Note that the `0,0` argument to `outer_join` means "substitute zeros if either stream's value is missing".

In your case, since the first stream counts "started" tasks and the second stream counts "completed" tasks, you are likely to find cases when the first metric has more rows than the second one. If you want to do a left join operation, the syntax is `outer_join _, 0`. The underscore followed by 0 means "don't substitute anything if the first stream's value is missing, but do substitute a zero if the second stream's value is missing."