# MQL: checking for present value / optional

Tags: google-cloud-monitoring, monitoring-query-language

As in title i ask for optional or dynamic value presence check in script, my goal is only to combine 2 metrics of same type, so joining them would be also a solution.

I have 2 different routs for same metrics, getting answere only from one of them at a time. I'd like to group them into one dashboard like:

```
 fetch container |
{ metric custom.googleapis.com/http/.../count;
metric custom.googleapis.com/http/joe/.../count }
| join
```

I tried different combinations, outer_join 0 seemed closest, but having no traffic in one of routs causes:

```
> Input table 1 does not have time series identifier column
> 'metric.requestType' that is present in table 0.
```

NOTE: One endpoind is NOT connected at all for a period of time

Configurationin similar for each in metrics.yaml:

```
---
apiVersion: monitoring.cnrm.cloud.google.com/v1beta1
kind: MonitoringMetricDescriptor
metadata:
  labels:
    app: << app_name >>
  name: custom/http/client/custom/requests/count
  namespace: << project_name >>
spec:
  type: custom.googleapis.com/http/client/custom/requests/count
  metricKind: GAUGE
  valueType: INT64
  labels:
  - key: pod_name
```

Comment: Is your issue resolved? If yes, can you provide the resolution steps you have followed and provide it as an answer for the greater visibility of the community.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to try `outer_join 0,0`. I've not tested this, but the suggestion was taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/70595836 which states that it will substitute zeros if either stream's value is missing. There's a couple of variations on this depending on what you want to do.